# Pygame interpreter

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, pygame

I want to be able to use a program in my web browser (and Safari on iOS).
How can I do this?
I believe that you can convert the program into JS and have a built in telling you when you find pygame, and then refer to this directory:

```
C:\python27\lib\site-packages\pygame
```

Comment: Pygame can now run in the browser see github.com/pygame-web ( demo pmp-p.github.io/pygame-wasm/ )

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is impossible. I had the same plan but eventually had to give up.

My suggestion: Learn JavaScript (very good tutorial: http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript from this website: http://www.codecademy.com ) then use Phaser: https://phaser.io/

That's the route I took after figuring out, that there's no way to get Pygame working in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but I found [Brython](http://www.brython.info/). Then you don't convert anything.

Comment: it doesn't support pygame. plus its 185,000 times slower than python

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible since you're not using python at all, but js. Also, Pygame is a set of Python modules built on top of the SDL library. It can't be embedded into web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  There are cross-compilers that convert Python to Javascript, but they won't support Pygame.  Pygame is built on the more low-level SDL library, which is not made for browsers.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bendmorris/pyj2d

I never used it but have seen this awhile back

Description:
PyJ2D module was modelled on Pygame commands that permits scripts coded in Python/Pygame to run in the Java virtual machine (JVM) using the Jython interpreter. This permits the deployment of JVM applications without extensive editing of the script. The current version of the module only supports a subset of Pygame functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this https://github.com/jggatc/pyjsdl .
It works with pyjamas http://pyjs.org/ .